# PHP permission of directory

Tags: php

How to check permissions of directory in PHP

```
$filename = 'dev\permis';
$handle = fopen($filename.'\file.txt', "w");
if (is_writable($filename)) 
{
    echo 'The directory is writeable';
} 
else
{
    echo 'The directory is not writable';
}
```

1. when i set permisson for permis folder is write ,

   the file.txt is created and browser " The directory is writeable"
2. when i set permisson for permis folder is deny write ,

   the file.txt is not created and browser is still " The directory is write" , why not "The directory is not writeable"

How to check permission of folder permisson ?

Comment: Are you on Windows? What version of PHP? Some older versions had a bug with this function in Windows that would cause it to report true.  The only other thing I can think of is that it's some kind of OS problem. The code looks fine.

Comment: window xp sp2,
php 5.1.12,and i run it on localhost.How i can check if i want use older php versions

Answer (score 0):

Did you call [clearstatcache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) between runs of this script?

Comment: i added clearstatcache function , but nothing changed.I run it on localhost.what diffirent betwwen run it on localhost and host ?